# Writing simple base code for a program that keeps track of my work hours and pay in C

Tags: c

When I compile my code it says that everything checks out but when I run it nothing happens. The program just runs until I kill the terminal.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float work;
    work=0;
    char ans[]="No";
    while(ans[0]=='N');
    {
        printf("Hours worked today ");
        scanf("%f", &work);
        printf("Is that all? ");
        scanf("%s", ans);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is why you should check the return value of `scanf()`....

Comment: remove the `;` after `while(ans[0]=='N');`

Answer (score 3):

You have put a `;` after the `while` condition. Therefore your while loop is empty and will run forever.

The more readable equivalent of *your* program is this:

```
int main()
{
   float work;
   work=0;
   char ans[]="No";
   while(ans[0]=='N')  
   {
    // empty loop thAT will run forever
   }

   // we never get here

   printf("Hours worked today ");
   scanf("%f", &work);
   printf("Is that all? ");
   scanf("%s", ans);

   return 0;
}
```

In your program juste change

```
while(ans[0]=='N');
```

to

```
while(ans[0]=='N')
```

and it will work.

Answer (score 2):

```
char ans[]="No";
...
scanf("%s", ans);
```

`ans` can hold only a string of length 2. You should make `ans` larger, to be able to hold any reasonable input, e.g.:

```
char ans[200] = "No";
```

---

Another problem is the `;` after the while:

```
while(ans[0]=='N');
                  ^
```

Remove it. It makes an empty instruction the only thing the `while` repeats.

---

Another thing: when dealing with user input, be it stdin or file input, you should check if the read was done successfully, in you case you should check the return value of [scanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf)

Answer (score 0):

Simply change

```
while(ans[0]=='N');
```

to

```
while(ans[0]=='N')
```

, because the former is identical to

```
while(ans[0]=='N')
{
    ;
}
```

,which will never end.